# Python: TypeError: function takes at least 2 arguments

Tags: python

when I do some exercises in the book --Machine learning in Action, in the dating matching problem, I meet the following problem, but I don't know why!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(stdin)", line 1, in (module)
  File 'kNN.py', line 27 ,in file2matrix
     fr = open(filename)
TypeError: function takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Here is my code:

```
    from numpy import *
    import operator
    from os import *

def file2matrix(filename):
    fr = open(filename)
    arrayOLines = fr.readlines()
    numberOfLines = len(arrayOLines)
    returnMat = zeros((numberOfLines,3))
    classLabelVector = []
    index = 0
    for line in arrayOLines:
        line = line.strip()
        listFromLine = line.split('\t')
        returnMat[index,:] = listFromLine[0:3]
        classLabelVector.append(int(listFromLine[-1]))
        index += 1
    return returnMat,classLabelVector
```

I made the modification,but the problem still exists!
It describe the kNN algorithm.

Comment: Which of those lines is line 27?

Comment: Why do you have double parentheses when calling your `zeros` method? `zeros((numberOfLines,3))`.

Comment: @idjaw zeros, if it's the numpy function, accepts a tuple as input for shape. That shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: @idjaw: That's how [`numpy.zeros`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) takes arguments, and it definitely looks like that's supposed to be `numpy.zeros`.

Comment: @Smac89: That's a `numpy` multidimensional array presumably; slicing via `tuple`s is legal and often necessary with `numpy` `array`s.

Comment: Well. I'm done guessing. :)

Comment: `fr= open(filename, 'r')`

Comment: Wild psychic guess: You clearly used `from numpy import *`, any chance you did that with some other package that defines an `open` function, or `int`, or `len`? Could be you imported something that shadows a Python built-in, and now it's screwing you over. Of course, this is why `from x import *` is generally frowned upon, it breaks namespacing, and you don't even specify what names to "unwrap".

Comment: @roadrunner66: `open`'s `mode` argument defaults `'r'`, passing it isn't necessary unless you're using something other than Python's built-in `open`. One of my bugaboos is code that insists on passing it needlessly, don't encourage it!

Comment: I bet it was [`os.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open). Seriously, don't use `import *`.

Comment: @user2357112: Ah, that's probably it. Was trying to think of an `open` that would need two arguments, and forgot the lowest level one of all. And `from os import *` would seem like an easy way to get all the names, even if it is a terrible, terrible idea.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, Ty, learnt something :)

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting the built-in open function with the one inside `os`:

```
In [1]: open?
Docstring:
open(name[, mode[, buffering]]) -> file object

Open a file using the file() type, returns a file object.  This is the
preferred way to open a file.  See file.__doc__ for further information.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method

In [2]: import os

In [3]: os.open?
Docstring:
open(filename, flag [, mode=0777]) -> fd

Open a file (for low level IO).
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

This is why you should avoid `from somewhere import *`